# How to insert a constant value for top 50 records in a table in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I have a table in MS Access wherein I have about a 100 records. I have a field called PRIORITY which needs to be populated with the word PRIORITY for the first 50 records only.

Kindly let me know if I can accomplish this via an SQL query.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.

With regards,
Manus

Comment: How do you determine which records are in the top 50?

Comment: Hello every one thanks for the quickreplies. I found a solution that works for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
UPDATE
(SELECT TOP 60 TOTAL_REVENUE,PRIORITY 
 FROM [MyTable]
 ORDER BY TOTAL_REVENUE DESC) AS a
SET a.PRIORITY = 'PRIORITY'
```

Hope this helps out.